# wikiprep MediaWiki::DumpFile namespace

Tags: perl, parsing, wikipedia

I am trying to use [wikiprep](https://github.com/kerzol/wikiprep) with support of [MediaWiki::DumpFile](http://search.cpan.org/~triddle/MediaWiki-DumpFile-0.2.2/) to parse wikipedia dump.

The problem is it doesn't work.

```
wikiprep -format composite -compress -f enwiki.xml.0001.gz
Can't locate object method "namespaces" via package "MediaWiki::DumpFile::Pages" at /usr/local/share/perl5/MediaWiki/DumpFile/Compat.pm line 148.
```

But I do have namespaces.

```
...
<siteinfo>
<sitename>Wikipedia</sitename>
<dbname>enwiki</dbname>
<base>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page</base>
<generator>MediaWiki 1.25wmf23</generator>
<case>first-letter</case>
<namespaces>
  <namespace key="-2" case="first-letter">Media</namespace>
  ...
```

I don't understand how to run this parser.

Comment: `Can't locate object method "namespaces" via package "MediaWiki::DumpFile::Pages"` has nothing to do with your input file; it means that the MediaWiki::DumpFile::Pages package doesn't provide a `namespaces` method. Do you perhaps have a really old version of MediaWiki::DumpFile::Pages? According to the docs, the `namespaces` method wasn't added until v0.0.7. Check your version with `perl -MMediaWiki::DumpFile::Pages -e 'print $MediaWiki::DumpFile::Pages::VERSION'`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, thank you very much for your comment, my version is 0.2.2.

Comment: Where I can get enwiki.xml.0001.gz in order to test your command?

Comment: anyway, let's continue our discussion [here](https://github.com/kerzol/wikiprep/issues/1)